# Array Null Foreach

Tags: php, arrays, mysqli

Morning everyone,

My problem seems to be in my foreach loop but  I cant see the issue.

When I print my array I get this from my select statment.

```
array(41) {
  [0]=> array(4) {
    ["id"]=>
    string(1) "1"
    ["name"]=>
    string(14) "Indoor Cycling"
    ["time"]=>
    string(12) "6.15am – 7am"
    ["day"]=>
    string(1) "1"
  }
  [1]=> array(4) {
    ["id"]=>
    string(2) "73"
    ["name"]=>
    string(11) "Fast Blast "
    ["time"]=>
    string(6) "7.10am"
    ["day"]=>
    string(1) "5"
  }
}
```

So I try the standard for each loop.

```
foreach ($rows as $timetableitems) {
    $timetablearray[] = array(
        'name' => $timetableitems->name,
        'time'  => $timetableitems->time,
    );              
}
```

But when I try and var dump my $timetablearray I get the following.

```
array(41) {
  [0]=>
  array(2) {
    ["name"]=>
    NULL
    ["time"]=>
    NULL
  }
  [1]=>
  array(2) {
    ["name"]=>
    NULL
    ["time"]=>
    NULL
  }
```

Any help would be most appreciated, thanks.

Comment: You are calling the items like objects, not arrays?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
foreach ($rows as $timetableitems) {
    $timetablearray[] = array(
        'name' => $timetableitems['name'],
        'time'  => $timetableitems['time'],
    );              
}
```

You can not access `array` variables by `$timetableitems->name`. You have to use `$timetableitems['name']`

Comment: Thanks mate sorry did not notice.

Answer (score 4):

Instead of calling:

```
$timetableitems->name
```

use:

```
$timetableitems['name']
```

Because `$timetableitems` is an array, not an object. So you access its properties with key.

Answer (score 0):

Try `$timetableitems['name']` Instead of `$timetableitems->name`

`$timetableitems` is an array so you can use `$timetableitems[]` this format